# How to TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix when Stream may not contain complete Object

Tags: protobuf-net

I'm working on a new Buffering processor for our application and have had a fresh look at the Protobuf `Deserialize*` methods and have investigating using the following code, in my former version I had my own TypeIdentifier and LengthPrefix in front and then guaranteeing that I have a full block to Deserialise. For testing I have replaced my reading of a networkStream with reading random length chunks from a File written to disk using repeated calls into `SerializeWithLengthPrefix()`

But when I am traversing the mDatabuffer I get the `EndOfStreamException` being thrown. It's no big deal, just wanted to make sure I'm doing this correctly, as there is no guarantee that I will have a "full" block of data to process perfectly through the Deserialize call. I was initially doing TryReadLengthPrefix, but this seems cleaner.

```vb
Public Sub New(ByVal maximumPacketSize As Integer)
    mMaxSize = maximumPacketSize
    mDataBuffer = New MemoryStream()
    mTypeResolver = AddressOf PacketTypeResolver
End Sub

Public Sub ProcessBuffer(ByVal theData() As Byte, offset As Integer, 
                         ByVal bytesToRead As Integer)
    'append the data we have just received into our StreamBuffer so we can 
    '"move back" if we hit the end of stream whilst Deserializing
    mDataBuffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)
    mDataBuffer.Write(theData, offset, bytesToRead)
    mDataBuffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

    While mDataBuffer.Position < mDataBuffer.Length
        Dim currentPosition As Integer = CType(mDataBuffer.Position, Integer)
        Try
            Dim p As Object = Nothing
            If Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(mDataBuffer, 
                          PrefixStyle.Base128, mTypeResolver, p) Then
                If GetType(BasePacket).IsAssignableFrom(p.GetType) Then
                    Dim bufferedPacket As BasePacket = CType(p, BasePacket)
                    ''''Do stuff with the packet.
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As EndOfStreamException
            Dim tmpData As New MemoryStream()
            tmpData.Write(mDataBuffer.GetBuffer(), currentPosition, 
                          CType(mDataBuffer.Length - currentPosition, Integer))
            mDataBuffer.Dispose()
            mDataBuffer = tmpData
            Exit While
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.GetType.Name & "---" & ex.Message)
            Throw
        End Try
    End While
End Sub
```

(aside) For learning I'm wondering about the API design decision of not catching the  exception inside `TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Try` in `TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix` is not "try and silently give up if there is a problem", it is: "try to get another object from the stream, but return false if we have an EOF in the natural position (between objects)". If the data is non-empty but incomplete, or invalid: it will still tell you. Loudly.

If you are reading data and don't know if you have a complete object, then I would say either:

- write your own framing protocol, or
- use `TryReadLengthPrefix` to compute the length required, and buffer that much data